# dimens file in values-sw360dp clashes with nexus4 & nexus5 UI

Tags: android, xml, multiscreen

Creating an application in portrait mode where I have to align `Button` on image based on top margin. I'm using `dimens` file in `values-sw360dp` which is looking proper in **nexus 5** but the same values is not aligning the `Buttons` in **nexus 4** as both of the devices using `values-sw360dp` folder for dimens file.

Can you please suggest the solution for this. Also can any one provide list of all possible values folder that should be integrated to support multiple screens

Following is the code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/windowBackground">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bc_logo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:src="@drawable/bc_imgbc_logo" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bc_logo"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/bc_img_margin_top">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/login_btn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="@drawable/signing_tab_btn"
            android:text="SIGN IN"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />

        <Button

            android:id="@+id/registration_btn"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="REGISTER"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />


    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout
```

In above code I need to align the `LinearLayout` on the `ImageView` so using `android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/bc_img_margin_top"`for setting margin.

I have the Image in `<ImageView/>` which i have to give height and width as match parent in order to maintain aspect ratio and occupy width of screen so this results in the image showing in the area i wanted top of screen but the `<ImageView/>` is occupying area of whole screen and I want to align the `<LinearLayout/>` having buttons on the bottom part of Image.

Following is the image in which the **sign in** button with yellow underline and **register** button in white text needs to be aligned on bottom most part of the image where image ends. and the blue area depicts the area occupied by  which covers the whole device height.

[image]

Comment: You want to buttons to be touching bottom of the screen?

Comment: How much the difference comes between nexus 4 and 5?

Comment: + 14 to 15dp difference in nexus 4 compared to nexus 5

Comment: Here you need to use frame layout instead of relative layout. its a kind of over lay you can play one view over another.

Comment: @RohitHeera can you please provide example using above XML code ?

Answer (score 0):

```
you need to add some values by yourself like backgrounds and dimensions...


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00FF00">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bc_logo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/background" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:weightSum="1"

        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/login_btn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"

            android:text="SIGN IN"
            android:textColor="#00FFFF" />

        <Button

            android:id="@+id/registration_btn"

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="REGISTER"
            android:textColor="#00FFFF" />


</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I cant use framelayout as the layout components below both sigin and register button gets screwed and I am facing issue of dimens value for margins provided for buttons alignment in nexus 4&5 and nexus 6 and nexus 9 as 4&5 uses sw360dp folder and dont know which folders to be created for nexus 6 and nexus 9?

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Create this kind of value structre for different sizes