# Handling Dynamically added Table Rows xml Layout in TableLayout Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablelayout

I have a `TableLayout` in fragment with following code:

```
<TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/projectsTableLayout"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">
</TableLayout>
```

This is the **AddMore** button which is below the `TableLayout` tag:

```
<Button
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
  android:id="@+id/add_more_projects_btn"
  android:text="@string/addmore"
  android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
  android:layout_below="@+id/projectsTableLayout"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
  android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>
```

Also I have created `TableRow` layout in separate xml file with following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/project_name__ET"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:hint="@string/projectnametxt"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/yearProjectTypeLinearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="05dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/yearSpinner"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
                android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/projectTypeSpinner"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
                android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TableRow>
```

What I want to implement is when the application loads I will be dynamically add rows 5 times.

I want to add 5 more rows on the **Add More** button click. Also I have to send all the values to the webserver when the user moves ahead in the application.

I am confused how should provide the ID to the components like(`EditText`, `Spinners`) in the Rows of table and retrieve it when the user moves to next screen.

I want to code in such a way so it can be optimised and easy to retrieve all the data for as many rows added to `TableLayout` on the AddMore Button click.

How to retrieve values and set ids for Row Components.

**EDIT ::**

*Modification of code as suggested by @Rohit Heera*

I have written following code:

```
        projectTableLayout = (TableLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.projectsTableLayout);
        projectTableLayout.setStretchAllColumns(true);

        yearAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, Constants.YEAR_ARRAY);
        projectTypeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, Constants.PROJECT_TYPE_ARRAY);
        projectListData = new ArrayList<ProjectData>();

        for(int i = 0; i < 5 ; i++)
        {
            tableRowStartCount = i;
            TableRow projectItemRow = new TableRow(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().getApplicationContext().LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            projectItemRow.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f));
            View projectRowView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.project_row_item,projectItemRow,false);


            projectNameET = (EditText) projectRowView.findViewById(R.id.project_name__ET);

            yearSpinner = (Spinner) projectRowView.findViewById(R.id.yearSpinner);
            yearSpinner.setAdapter(yearAdapter);

            projectTypeSpinner = (Spinner) projectRowView.findViewById(R.id.projectTypeSpinner);
            projectTypeSpinner.setAdapter(projectTypeAdapter);
            projectItemRow.addView(projectRowView);

            ProjectData projectObj = new ProjectData();
            projectListData.add(projectObj);

            projectTableLayout.addView(projectItemRow,tableRowStartCount);
        }
```

Can you please let me know how can i implement the eventlistener in the above loop?

Comment: Please upload some screenshots to explain it better

Answer (score 1):

```
Use this code to add rows in table 
/**
     * this method add the dynamic table row and display the list .
     */
    public void displayList(List<Data> datalist) {
        int i = 0;
        TableLayout projectsTableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.projectsTableLayout);
        projectsTableLayout.removeAllViews();
        for (i = 0; i <= datalist.size(); i++) {

            TableRow singleTableRow = new TableRow(this);

            LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.addattendeelistdata, null);

            RelativeLayout parentRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.comleteRL);

            EditText project_name__ET = (EditText) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.project_name__ET);
            Spinner yearSpinner = (Spinner) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.yearSpinner);
            Spinner projectTypeSpinner = (Spinner) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.projectTypeSpinner);


            singleTableRow.addView(view);

            /** Add row to TableLayout. */

            projectsTableLayout.addView(singleTableRow, i);

        }


    }

And for get Reference for each object you need to Create seperate class .
If you tell me on which event you can move to next class so i can help you better.

Thanks
```

Comment: And for get Reference for each object you need to Create seperate class .
If you tell me on which event you can move to next class so i can help you better.

Comment: I will switch to next activity from this fragment on the button click event on actionbar so I want to retrieve all the values from all the rows and their components so I can submit it to webserver. Can you let me know how to retrieve values from all the rows?

Comment: you need to create a model class for three values one for edit text and two for spinner i will provide code to you..

Comment: Can you look into this question also if you have any solution. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31114670/dimens-file-in-values-sw360dp-clashes-with-nexus4-nexus5-ui

Comment: Yes i can suggest a suitable change in the layout.

Answer (score 0):

```
Like Edit Text you need to create separte class for spinner item listeners and store the value and main list automatically get all the new values.

/**
     * this method add the dynamic table row and display the list .
     */

     List<ProjectData> mainList=new List<ProjectData>();

     // calling function
     displayList(mainList);



    public void displayList(List<ProjectData> datalist) {
        int i = 0;
        TableLayout projectsTableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.projectsTableLayout);
        projectsTableLayout.removeAllViews();
        for (Iterator<ProjectData> it :datalist.hasNext();) {

            TableRow singleTableRow = new TableRow(this);

            LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.addattendeelistdata, null);

            RelativeLayout parentRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.comleteRL);

            EditText project_name__ET = (EditText) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.project_name__ET);
            Spinner yearSpinner = (Spinner) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.yearSpinner);
            Spinner projectTypeSpinner = (Spinner) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.projectTypeSpinner);
            project_name__ET.addTextChangedListener(new ListenEditText(it.next()) );

            singleTableRow.addView(view);

            /** Add row to TableLayout. */

            projectsTableLayout.addView(singleTableRow, i);

        }


    }

    class ListenEditText implements TextWatcher
    {
        ProjectData data;
        ListenEditText(ProjectData data)
        {
            this.data=data;

        }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            data.project_name=s.toString();

        }}


    ModelClass;

    class ProjectData
    {
    public String project_name;
    public String year;
    public String projectType;
    }
```

Comment: can you tell me Why used Iterator<ProjectData> in for loop didnt understand the concept of it. Also can you please provide the seperate class for spinner. and the function displayList is used for retreiving values from the rows Am I correct?

Comment: Its  a concept of reflection when you use Itetaror the change in the inner list directly reflect in the original list thats why we use iterator when you press the button the main list get all the updated value.

Comment: but for that i need to create instance objects of projectdata and store in datalist every time i create new rows dynamically? how does the user selected values on the spinners and edit text maintained and stored for retrieval ?

Comment: Yes the number of rows you want is the sixe of the list is the only way to get the updated value

Comment: One more doubt when the app 1st creates the rows the datalist i.e. Iterator<ProjectData> it :datalist.hasNext(); will have no values in it so how will the forloop work?

Comment: In that case loops never run

Comment: if loop will not work than how will the following command be executed :

project_name__ET.addTextChangedListener(new ListenEditText(it.next()) );

Comment: Budy u need to the blank obkects in the list first then  like if you have 5 items than  do   the following: for(int i=0;i<5;i++) { ProjectData data = new ProjectData(); mainlist.add(data);}  then after that call display fynction

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82163/discussion-between-niranjan-balkrishna-prajapati-and-rohit-heera).